# Delphi 2009/2010 and Access 2007 database

Tags: delphi, ms-access

How to connect to a accdb using Delphi 2009/2010 and adoconnection (design time)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OleDB Provider` instead of `Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE Db provider` on the connection string.

If you don't have the Acccess 2007 or 2010 instead on the machine, you can download the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en)

Comment: See [Connection strings for Access 2007](http://connectionstrings.com/access-2007).